# Voltage of a battery in a circuit with an infinite resistance

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering, batteries

I have a dilemma that I would like to share with you concerning batteries (without neglecting internal resistance), emf and resistance of a circuit.
To better visualize my question you may need to check these pictures:

[image: zero resistance circuit]
[image: Infinite resistance circuit]

-First, I'm trying to grasp the concept of why and how the voltage drop at the terminals of a battery depends on the resistance of the circuit.

-Second, knowing that $$\epsilon= V_b + V_c$$ (battery and circuit, respectively), we know that $$\epsilon=I(R+r)$$
Considering the extreme cases where $R=0$ and $R=∞$,
what I expected was that at $R = ∞$, the voltage would be 0, because there would be infinite resistance and zero current, and since $V=RI$, it would be $V= ∞ \times 0=0$ which makes absolutely no sense to me. Plus, an ideal voltmeter has an infinite resistance but it does not give a voltage reading of zero when its terminals are placed on the battery terminals.

What am I doing wrong, and how do the charges on the poles of the battery act in each of these cases?

I'm sorry I could not be clearer in how to propose the question but I hope that it is enough. I'm still learning so do not rely on any of my assumptions.

Comment: ... but $\infty\times 0\neq 0$ (see [Indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form))

Comment: physicists divide and multiply with infinity all the time, Mathematical rigor gets in the way too much.

Comment: At R→∞ voltage won't be 0 but little less than EMF off cell, since a series circuit with voltmeter and battery is complete.

Comment: Could you clarify which voltage you are labeling as V_circuit?

Comment: An Ideal voltmeter cannot tell you voltage across resistance in practical

Comment: I think the voltmeter would measure the voltage drop across the circuit which is in turn across the external resistor. @Gus

Comment: @AnubhavGoel you mean that at as R approaches infinity the voltage through the resistor approaches zero? and therefore according to Kirchoff's voltage law the voltage of the battery will approach the emf and not zero? ah now im getting it, i was really confused by the fact that (i thought) infinity*0=0. Thanks

Comment: You got it almost right. I also came to ∞*0≠ 0, a month back.

Comment: Yes, voltage across resistor reaches 0.Voltmeter reading is not EMF because it draw some current which pass through internal r and gets some potential across it.

Comment: @KyleKanos why is this question closed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At R→∞ voltage won't be 0 but little
less than EMF off cell, since a series
circuit with voltmeter and battery is
complete.

Yes, voltage across resistor reaches
0.Voltmeter reading is not EMF
because it draw some current which
pass through internal r and gets some
potential across it.

An Ideal voltmeter cannot tell you
voltage across resistance in practical.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have faced a conceptual problem because you have used the relationship $V=RI$, rather you should have been using the definition of resistance $R = \frac V I$.
Then as $V$ goes up and $I$ goes down the value of $R$ increases.
Also you must be careful about $I=0$ (current equals exactly zero) and $I\rightarrow0$ (current gets closer and closer to zero).

When $R$ is large it might be better to redraw the circuit diagram with the resistor $R$ being replaced by a leaky capacitor.  With no measuring instruments the circuit diagram is as follows:

[image]

If you wait long enough the potential difference across the leaky capacitor will be $\frac{\mathcal{E}R}{(r+R)}$.

As the resistance increases the potential difference across the leaky capacitor will get closer to $\mathcal{E}$.

You can show that there is charge stored on the leaky capacitor and hence a potential difference across the leaky capacitor by disconnecting the leaky capacitor from the circuit and connected the ends of the leaky capacitor with a wire to find that a current flows in the wire.

Now measurement of the potential difference with a voltmeter could be tricky.

[image]

The reason being that the voltmeter has the potential of disturbing the circuit because it will have a resistance $R_V$ and so the current $i$ in the circuit will increase resulting in the potential difference across the leaky capacitor decreasing due to a greater potential difference across $r$.
The larger you make $R_V$ the closer voltmeter reading will be to $\frac{\mathcal{E}R}{(r+R)}$.

What I have tried to show is that what you can do using an abstraction is not necessarily realisable in practice.  So you can imagine $R$ getting larger and larger and using a voltmeter whose resistance is much, much larger that $R$ but it is another thing actually being able to do that in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

> -First, I'm trying to grasp the concept of why and how the voltage drop at the terminals of a battery depends on the resistance of the circuit.

The EMF, $\mathcal{E}$, exists chemically and is always present. If there is a path for current to flow, then there will be a voltage drop across the internal resistance, $r$, and the external resistance, $R$.  For short periods of use of the battery $r$ will remain constant. That means the current is regulated by $R$ via $$I=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{(r+R)}.$$ (Notice that $\mathcal{E}$ is **not regulated** by this equation.) The terminal voltage measured for the battery will be $\mathcal{E}$ dropped by the internal resistance voltage drop, $Ir$.  As $R$ changes, so does the current and the terminal voltage.

If the external resistance, $R$, becomes extremely large, $R\to\infty$, the current drops to zero and the internal voltage drop $Ir$ goes to zero, leaving $\mathcal{E}$ by itself as the terminal voltage.

$V=IR$ is very specific to individual resistors and really should be though of as $V_R=I_RR$, and doesn't (neglecting internal resistance effects) affect regulated or chemical voltage *sources*.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that infinite resistance is equal to an open circuit. In real life if you have a battery not connected to anything, there will always be a voltage across the terminals. Even a lead-acid car battery will produce sparks if you short the terminals!